# Render Silverlight Animation to video file

Tags: wpf, silverlight, video, expression, expression-encoder

I need to be able to render a silverlight storyboard animation to video. The animated content itself could be simple UIElements, Images or even two or more videos playing at the same time.

Several ideas came to mind like RenderTargetBitmap on a single frame basis, but:

1) I've never tested this against video embedded content

2) Don't know how to actually compose the video from the generated images.

Expression Encoder was also on my mind, but I don't know if it's possible to integrate it in a Silverlight/XBAP app to fulfill what's expected from it.

What's your opinion on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you just need to capture this sort of thing would be to use the Expression Encoder 4's screen recording feature, or a tool like TechSmith Camtasia.